# junit4 clean DB after test

Tags: spring, junit4

I have a junit test that insert row into DB table 
but I dont have method to remove rows from this table(and I cannot add one).
Is there posibility to implement junit test that will clean
this table after test ends?
Im using :
Spring Framework 4.3.3
 with @SpringJUnit4ClassRunner class
and @ContextConfiguration annotation
and JUnit 4.12

thanks in advance for any suggestions
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the test with `@Transactional` and Spring will automatically clean everything up at the end of the test.

Comment: You make my day :)